# AES Decryption in objective c where encryption in .net

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

Hello friends I stuck in decryption of data. Server side data is encrypted by .net, i tried many codes but unable to decrypt.

In android data is decrypted by this function

```
public static String doDecrypt(String data, String key){
String decryptedData = null;
  try {
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
      byte[] b = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
      int len = b.length;
      if (len > keyBytes.length)
           len = keyBytes.length;
           System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
           SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
           IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
           cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
           byte[] results = new byte[data.length()];

     try {
          results = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(data,Base64.DEFAULT));
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.i("Erron in Decryption", e.toString());
    }
       Log.i("Data", new String(results, "UTF-8"));
       decryptedData = new String(results, "UTF-8");
     }
       catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
      return decryptedData;
    }
```

its working fine in android, but while decrypting in objective c its gives only null.
I used some link that are below:-

[nsdata](https://gist.github.com/matsuda/9204276) , [fwencryption](https://gist.github.com/FrankWu100/8048697) , [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor)

But it only gives null value when decrypting in NSString.

For example you can check a demo for decryption

```
      data:-1YbDEEZGnc5EtZY040AaSP233AXZHJVAZb74sCQHm+BX72N5nM81ygDsRHhF8KMk
       key- test@123456789
```

I used this code in Objective c

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NSData+AES.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


     NSString *testData = [self decode:@"1YbDEEZGnc5EtZY040AaSP233AXZHJVAZb74sCQHm+BX72N5nM81ygDsRHhF8KMk"];
    NSLog(@"Dtata%@",testData);
  }


 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
      [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




   -(NSString*)encode:(NSString*)plainString {

      //convert 'plainString' to NSData using NSUTF8StringEncoding
      NSData *plainData = [plainString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     //encrypt data with AES encryption
NSData *AESData = [plainData AES128EncryptedDataWithKey:@"test@123456789"];

      //return base64 encoded string
      return [AESData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    }


-(NSString*)decode:(NSString*)encodedString {

//convert 'encodedString' to base64 decoded data
NSData *base64Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:encodedString options:0];

//decode using AES encryption
NSData *AESData = [base64Data AES128DecryptedDataWithKey:@"test@123456789"];

//return string from AES decoded data
return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:AESData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Please anyone can help me out. I am stuck in this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Also, where is your Objective-C code? We normally cannot read minds.